# Depth configuration in fetch queries not using relationships directions in Neo4j OGM APIs

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using neo4j's **findAll() APIs (OGM 2.0.5)** to fetch nodes using filters, paging, sorting and custom depth. Everything is working perfectly, except that generated **cypher queries don't take relationships direction into account**:

```
MATCH (n)...
WHERE...
WITH n
MATCH p=(n)-[*0..d]-()
RETURN p
```

instead of:
    ...MATCH p=(n)-[*0..d]**->()**...

Is it really important for me, because not taking relationships directions into account **causes huge amount of nodes to be returned** by the query. For now **my only option is to write manually all my queries in CYPHER**.

Some times my **queries freeze or are extremely slow**. But they are very fast if I specify the direction manually.

It is possible/planned to let configure this behavior in order to have **optimized queries based on graph modelisation** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a feature request open for this one, you can track it here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/70